# syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'

Tags: php

```
$regexp = array (
            1 => "/\[{bbtag}](.+?)\[\/{bbtag}\]/is",
            2 => "/\[{bbtag}=(['"]?)(.+?)(['"]?)\](.+?)\[\/{bbtag}\]/is",
            3 => "/\[{bbtag}=(['"]?)(.+?)(['"]?),(['"]?)(.+?)(['"]?)\](.+?)\[\/{bbtag}\]/is"
            );
```

Ругается с этой строчки

```
2 => "/\[{bbtag}=(['"]?)(.+?)(['"]?)\](.+?)\[\/{bbtag}\]/is",
```

> syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'

Ошибка , как я понимаю связанна с версией php...
Помогите , новичку =)

Comment: Экранируйте кавычки в символьном классе: `['\"]`. Эта ошибка связана не с версией пхп, а с элементарным незнанием синтаксиса языка.

Comment: Посмотрите, цвет текста посередине регулярного выражения отличается - красный строковой литерал меняется на чёрный. Это явно указывает на ошибку синтаксиса. Рекомендую включить подстветку синтаксиса в вашем редакторе кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо экранировать кавычки

```
\"
```

---

```
$regexp = array (
            1 => "/\[{bbtag}](.+?)\[\/{bbtag}\]/is",
            2 => "/\[{bbtag}=(['\"]?)(.+?)(['\"]?)\](.+?)\[\/{bbtag}\]/is",
            3 => "/\[{bbtag}=(['\"]?)(.+?)(['\"]?),(['\"]?)(.+?)(['\"]?)\](.+?)\[\/{bbtag}\]/is"
            );
```

Comment: Очень Вам балгодарен , Спасибо за помощь.